# Domain forwarding using 123-reg doesn't support HTTPS but is indexed in Google with it

Tags: domains, https, domain-forwarding, 123-reg

I have set up a forwarder on my domain to go to one of my social media profiles.

This works fine if I visit my domain directly e.g. `www.loremipsum.co.uk`, but if I search my name in Google and find my domain that way, I get a `This site can’t be reached` error when I visit the page.

I think Google is displaying a `https://` link in its results. If I change the URL in my browser to `http://` then the link works fine and it sends me to my social media page.

I'm managing my domain in 123-Reg, but I see no option in the web forwarders section to choose between http and https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear. As you pointed out, the https version of the site is indexed in Google but is not answering.

HTTPS sites are harder to redirect as they require a certificate (which needs to be requested in a per site basis) unlike http which can be handled en-masse with a single setup with some database matching.  It is probable that 123-reg is not doing https forwarding.

For sites I manage I either set up basic hosting with just a redirect for the old site + an exception for the https verification or I send both the old and new site to the same virtual host, add both old and new hosts to the certificate and set up redirection for anything except the cannonical URL to the cannonical one.  You likely need to fo something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and was inspired by davidgo's answer to try turning on SSL, which seems to have solved it. In Google Domains, here's the step-by-step, as of May 2023:

1. In "My Domains", click "Manage" to the right side of relevant domain.
2. On the new left-side menu, select "Website".
3. On the right, this should make "Edit forwarding" available, click that.
4. At the bottom of the options, there should be a pulldown labeled "Advanced options".
5. Inside the pulldown, select "SSL On."
6. Hit the big blue "Forward" button to save the change, and bob's your uncle.  It'll take a few hours to start working.

Comment: The domain name would need to be transferred from 123-reg to Google Domains to be able to use your solution.